# Null character in Sql Injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Going through sql injection on hakipedia, i understand that the injections are assumed to go along a parameter (which becomes a part of the sql query at the server end).

e.g.

```
select news from news_table where id=1
```

is attacked as

```
select news from news_table where id=NULL UNION ALL select * from users
```

However, in information schema (http://hakipedia.com/index.php/SQL_Injection#INFORMATION_SCHEMA) and Mysql Benchmark (http://hakipedia.com/index.php/SQL_Injection#MySQL_BENCHMARK) injection vector the NULL before UNION ALL is not explicitly stated. Is this correct or am i missing something?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ (SCNR)

Comment: @luksch Yeah. have seen it before :) lol

Comment: I seriously have no idea why my questions are being downvoted. This is probably not the first time.

Comment: i gave it a +1 to make it even again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NULL` is just used to make the starting query valid. Those are probably just examples to use as starting points. You may need to tweak the attack for different queries. For example, if the query ends with a string parameter:

```
... where id = 'abc'
```

The code may look something like this:

```
"... where id = '${id}'"
```

The attack would need to correctly terminate that statement to make it valid SQL. Something like this may work:

```
' UNION ALL select * from users --
```

Which would result in:

```
... where id = '' UNION ALL select * from users --'
```

The NULL example would probably not work here. It would result in something like this:

```
... where id = 'NULL UNION ALL select * from users'
```

Comment: Thanks :) So much more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The NULL before UNION makes sure that there are no news in the result set since there shouldn't be any rows in news_table without an id set i.e. *id=NULL*. You could also try -1 instead of NULL.

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of the NULL in the above query. The intention of the query is just to return the News column from the news table for the selected article. Hacker supplies a NULL value, which is never *equal* to anything, and thus the first query will not return a row. As part of the supplied parameter for the hack, they attempt to return results from the users table. Assuming the value for id are the positive set of integers, supply an attack string of `-1  UNION ALL select * from users` would have done the same thing.

Unless it's a COTS product where the schema is known, once you discover a site is vulnerable to an injection attack the next step is to figure out what the underlying RDBMS is and then what data is available. The benchmark things would be what I would use to see if a web response that is usually instantaneous is now taking 5, 10, 30 seconds. That tells me I have a good idea that this is a MySQL target.

The next challenge is getting the data out. In the above, only one column of data is returned but we have requested all the columns. That won't compile, at least in the SQL Server world, because the engine will see that the first is returning 1 column and the second is returning N columns. Instead, you'd need to either selectively return columns or concatenate them all together.

If you were simply going the malicious route, this is where it's easier as all you do is substitute in your delete/drop commands and not worry about shaping the attacked output into a predefined shape.